# Replace characters in string up to a specific character. Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a string:

"category / card"

what I want to do is to transform that string into "card"

so basically I'm deleting everything up until and including the "/" character.

How do I do that ?

Comment: `.slice()` in jQuery and `.substr() and .indexOf()` can be used.

Comment: `String.split(' / ')[1]`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str="category / card";
str = str.substr(str.lastIndexOf("/")+1).trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str="category / card";
str=str.split('/')[1];
```